# VBA to count cells by colour in one column when a specific word in another column

Tags: excel, vba, string, colors, count

I'm trying to find some VBA to count cells by colour in a range when there is specific word in an adjacent range.

I've found VBA to count cells by colour but I want to extend this so that I only count the colour when a certain word appears in another range. I found something that will almost do it but the VBA looks for words and colours in the same range. I did find this, an exchange between Algo and Shai Rado but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Function ConditionalColorFunction(rColor As Range, rColoredRange As Range, StrCond As String, rCondRange As Range) As Long

    Dim rColoredCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iCondRangeColumnsAmount As Integer
    Dim vResult

    lCol = rColor.Interior.Color
    iCondRangeColumnsAmount = rCondRange.Columns.Count

    For Each rColoredCell In rColoredRange
        If rColoredCell.Interior.Color = lCol Then
           For i = 1 To iCondRangeColumnsAmount
               If Cells(rColoredCell.Row, i).Value = StrCond Then
                   vResult = 1 + vResult
                   Exit For
               End If
           Next
        End If
    Next rColoredCell

    ConditionalColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your post. As I see it at the moment, `rColor` is a cell containing the *color*, `rColoredRange` is a range with multiple columns (some of the cells are highlight in the *color*), and `rCondRange` is a single-column range (some cell values are equal to `strCond`) with the same number of rows as `rColoredRange`. Whether it is like I see it or not, you need to clarify even more than that. A screenshot of your worksheet would clarify a lot.

Comment: @Kavorka, thanks for your interest. Screen shot below. You are right your thoughts, though  rColoredRange only need be a column and strCond will be equal to a word/string.

Comment: @Kavorka, sorry still I'm trying to figure out how to add a screen shot.. basically I have two columns, one is headed requirements (random text, colour coded by status ie red=bad) and one headed owner. Each requirement is assigned an owner and I want to know how many 'red' requirements each owner has. I can't use Countif because it doesn't recognise colours. I plan to apply this to many times to other attributes too. Thanks

Comment: I think you meant to tag @VBasic2008, all I did is format your code

Answer (score 2):

### Count Colored Cells With Condition

- Note that this should **not** be used as a UDF since it only updates if the **values** in the Criteria column change but not when the **colors** in the Color column do.

[image]

```vb
Function ConditionalColorFunction( _
    ByVal ColorCell As Range, _
    ByVal ColorRange As Range, _
    ByVal CriteriaString As String, _
    ByVal CriteriaRange As Range) _
As Long

    Dim Color As Long: Color = ColorCell.Interior.Color

    Dim cCell As Range, r As Long, Result As Long, CondString As String

    For Each cCell In ColorRange.Cells
        r = r + 1
        If cCell.Interior.Color = Color Then
            CondString = CStr(CriteriaRange.Cells(r).Value)
            If StrComp(CondString, CriteriaString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Result = Result + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next cCell

    ConditionalColorFunction = Result

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks VBasic2008 works a treat - both methods :)

Comment: Just experimenting, I see what you mean about not updating with the colour change. As soon as you change any of the strings it updates and captures any colour change. Is there a way around this, otherwise it's perfect. If not I will just have to remember to change a string to update it.

Comment: Sorry, no workaround I'm aware of. Double-clicking the resulting cell and pressing `Enter` is also a way to update (correct) the result. Also, you could add a button and assign it a single-liner Sub containing `Application.CalculateFull`.

Comment: Thanks again VBasic2008 the button works really well 

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly....

```
Function test(rColor As Range, rColoredRange As Range, StrCond As String, rCondRange As Range) As Long

lCol = rColor.Interior.Color

For Each r In rCondRange.Rows
    If Not r.Find(StrCond, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r.Row, rColoredRange.Column) _
                .Interior.Color = lCol Then cnt = cnt + 1
End If
Next

test = cnt

End Function
```

The function loop to each row of rCondRange, then check if it find the value of StrCond in the looped row. If found, then it check [the row of the looped row - the rColoredRange column] interior colos is lCol.

[image]

As seen in the animation above, the formula recalculate if there is a change within rCondRange. But if the change is about the color, it won't recalculate.

Please note, the function assumed that all the data is in Sheet1. So if for example you write the formula in Sheet2 in any cell something like this `=test(Sheet1!D1,Sheet1!G2:G16,"test",Sheet1!H2:I16)`, it still give a correct result.

But that's if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Hi Karma, thanks for your response, very good based on my information! There is only column D and E from your example so expect count 3. I have tried the script but it's not currently working for me unfortunately. I have made the cells in the script match to my corresponding cells but not sure why I need to plug the information in again when using the function ie rColor, rColoredRange, StrCond, rCondRange? Are these two different scripts...? Ideally I'd just like a function I can plug in the variables/ranges and not have to go into the script to change cell/sheet refsif possible? Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood you. I thought you want the count result within VBA. Please have a look to my revised code. The function then is written in a cell of the sheet to get the result.